# Data fetch between to dates in codignator

Tags: php

this is my controller

```
public function stock_report()
       {

        $key= $this->input->post('Txtname');
        $date1= $this->input->post('txt_to');
        $date2= $this->input->post('Txtfrom');
        $data['filter'] = $this->transfer_model->stock_report($key,$date1,$date2);  
        $this->load->view('layout/header');
        $this->load->view('layout/nav');
        $this->load->view('stock_report',$data);
        $this->load->view('layout/footer');
    }
```

this is my model code

```
public function stock_report($key,$date1,$date2)
{

    $this->db->select("*");
    $this->db->where('transfer_date<=',$date1);
    $this->db->where('transfer_date>=',$date2);
    $this->db->like("store",$key);
    $this->db->from("stock_transfer");
    $query = $this->db->get();
    return $query->result();

}
```

Comment: And what issue you are facing???

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NULL AND transfer_date > IS NULL AND store LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!'' at line 3 SELECT * FROM stock_transfer WHERE transfer_date < IS NULL AND transfer_date > IS NULL AND store LIKE '%%' ESCAPE '!' Line Number: 691

Comment: Do the `$date1` and `$date2` have values? have you checked it? and also you need to escape the string by using `$this->db->escape_like_str();` function

Comment: thanks bro salved :)